# Async - passing variables and preserving context

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

If you have the following code :

```
var asyncConfig = {};
var a, b;
for(var i = 0; i < someValue; i++) {
    // do something with a
    // do something with b
    asyncConfig[i] = function(callback) {
        func(a, b, callback); // func is async
    }
}
// Include some more parallel or series functions to asyncConfig
async.auto(asyncConfig);
```

- How can you pass the values of the variables `a` and `b` to  `func` so that when `async.auto(asyncConfig)` is executed after the `for` loop, the context of `a` and `b` is preserved ?

(Different context of `a` and `b` for every execution of `func`.)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var asyncConfig = {};
var a, b;
for(var i = 0; i < someValue; i++) {
    // do something with a
    // do something with b
    (function(a,b){
      asyncConfig[i] = function(callback) {
        func(a, b, callback); // func is async
      }
    })(a,b);
}
// Include some more parallel or series functions to asyncConfig
async.auto(asyncConfig);
```

Comment: Does anyone else think it's absurd that we have to do this? All I want is to pass some of my current state into this task executor. In coffeescript my code looked like this:

`_metadata = do (metadata) -> (callback) -> callback(null, metadata);
async.auto(metadata: _metadata)`

It seems to me that some major bugs will appear in the future given this workaround.

Comment: You could also use ```myFunction.bind(null, a, b)``` ?

Answer (score 1):

possible alternative using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
var asyncConfig = {};
var a, b;
for(var i = 0; i < someValue; i++) {
    // do something with a
    // do something with b
    asyncConfig[i] = func.bind(asyncConfig, a, b);
}
// Include some more parallel or series functions to asyncConfig
async.auto(asyncConfig);
```

Make sure to check if the environments where you use this support bind. Also, I am binding the "this" value to `asyncConfig`, this may not be appropriate for you.

edit : Reading over the question again, are a and b primitives or objects/arrays? If they aren't primitives, then you'll want to clone them.